# Sharepoint workflow error

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Please help me on this. I have created a workflow in which I am getting email for approval but for rejection I am not getting email. Kindly help me on this.

```
Step: Step 1
  Email Current Item:Approver name
  Wait for Approval Status to equal 0;#Approved
  If Current Item:Approval Status equals 0;#Approved
    If Current Item:System Name equals Adrenalin
      Email Asik Adam (External)
    Else if Current Item:Approval Status equals 1;#Rejected
      Email Asik Adam (External)
    Else if Current Item:System Name equals MS Dynamics AX
      Email Asik Adam (External)
    Else
    If Current Item:System Name equals Windows
      Email Asik Adam (External)
  Step: Step 2
    If Current Item:Approval Status equals 1;#Rejected
      Email Asik Adam (External)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your indention reflects the real parentheses then you Else if Current Item:Approval Status equals 1;#Rejected condition checked AFTER you ALREADY know that Status=Approved.

Try this indention:

```
Step: Step 1
Email Current Item:Approver name
Wait for Approval Status to equal 0;#Approved
If Current Item:Approval Status equals 0;#Approved
  If Current Item:System Name equals Adrenalin
    Email Asik Adam (External)
  Else if Current Item:System Name equals MS Dynamics AX
    Email Asik Adam (External)
  Else
    If Current Item:System Name equals Windows
      Email Asik Adam (External)
Else if Current Item:Approval Status equals 1;#Rejected
  Email Asik Adam (External)
Step: Step 2
 If Current Item:Approval Status equals 1;#Rejected
   Email Asik Adam (External)
```